# Javascript url query string

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm a newbie to javascript, and I'm trying to create a dynamic variable in Google Tag Manager, I currently have this script

```
function() {
var test1 = 'hello'
var newURL = window.location.href
  
if (typeof test1!= 'undefined')  
    return newURL;
else
    return newURL + '?utm_param' + test1;
}
```

With this, I will have output like http://www.test.com/?utm_param=hello

If I want to have a dynamic query string, if the URL ended with `test.com/?test1=test&utm_param=hello`
how do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: `typeof test1!= 'hello'` is always true. Can you fix your code first?

Comment: it should be fixed now, sorry about that,

Comment: See urlsearchparams... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function() {
  var test1 = 'hello'
  var newURL = new URL(window.location.href)

  if (typeof test1 === 'undefined') {
    newURL.searchParams.append('utm_param', test1);
  }
  return newURL.toString();
}
```

Comment: Do searchparams works in all browser? I thought I read somewhere it has limitations, for example IE? Thanks!

Comment: check here https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams
if it doens't then you can easily include a polyfill for it